# How to change default/start value of JSlider

Tags: java, swing, jslider

I am wondering how I can change my start value of the JSlider I am using.

My code looks like this:

```
public ScaleController() {
// SLIDER 1:
// --------------------------------------------------------------------
    setOrientation(SwingConstants.VERTICAL);
    addChangeListener(this);
    setMajorTickSpacing(10);
    setPaintTicks(true);
    setMaximum(50);
    setMinimum(-50);

    Hashtable<Integer, JLabel> labelTable = new Hashtable<Integer, JLabel>();

    labelTable.put(new Integer(50), new JLabel("Zoom +5"));
    labelTable.put(new Integer(0), new JLabel("Zoom 0"));
    labelTable.put(new Integer(-50), new JLabel("Zoom -5"));
    setLabelTable(labelTable);

    setPaintLabels(true);

@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
  Controller.setZoom(getValue());
}
```

I want the default value to be 0, so it starts in the middle of my slider, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: hmm ... what's wrong with `setValue(0)`

Comment: does setValue(n) not work? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JSlider.html#setValue%28int%29

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setValue(0)` would work in your case
check [API here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSlider.html#setValue%28int%29)

Comment: Solved the problem with some help from Kleopatra and Jaydee.
All I needed was: setValue(0); I tried with setDefaultValue(0); before.