# How to modify JSlider value after initialisation

Tags: java, jslider

I am making a program for offline and online use. Whenever this application boots, it creates a JFrame with a JSlider on there, with a default value of 7. Whenever you login and go online it should update the value on the JSlider. I was wondering if there was a way to change this value without disposing the current jframe and making a new one.

**The slider object**

```
 soundVolumeSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(1);
    soundVolumeSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
    soundVolumeSlider.setBounds(15, 120, 215, 45);
    soundVolumeSlider.setValue(Main.soundVolume);
    soundVolumeSlider.addChangeListener(new onSoundSliderChange());
    soundVolumeSlider.setPaintLabels(true);
    settingsContent.add(soundVolumeSlider);
```

**The change listener**

```
@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent event) 
{
     Main.soundVolume = soundVolumeSlider.getValue();
     soundHandler.changeVolume(Main.soundVolume, soundHandler.soundClip);
}
```

Comment: do you mean setValue is not firing change event?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change default/start value of JSlider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14812871/how-to-change-default-start-value-of-jslider)

Comment: setValue not taking effect on slider's visual on your frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're after is [`JSlider#setValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSlider.html#setValue%28int%29)

Take a look at [How to use JSlider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html) for more details